# Unable to get Facebook Cookie and execute code

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

since i am new in facebook graph API ,but i know the basics .Now i need help from you all that how to read User Wall Post and others who posted on wall of any user, with read_stream. But i dnt know how to call. I tried some way but i was able to read jus name and basic info. I need help in reading objects. Please help me!!!

```
<?php header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND    
 CNT"');?>
<?php

define('FACEBOOK_APP_ID', 'xxxxx');
define('FACEBOOK_SECRET', 'xxxxxxxxx');

function get_facebook_cookie($app_id, $application_secret) {
$args = array();
print_r($_COOKIE);
parse_str(trim($_COOKIE['fbs_' . $app_id], '\\"'), $args);
ksort($args);
$payload = '';
foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
    if ($key != 'sig') {
        $payload .= $key . '=' . $value;
    }
}
if (md5($payload . $application_secret) != $args['sig']) {
  return null;
}
return $args;
}

$cookie = get_facebook_cookie($app_id, $application_secret);
   echo 'The ID of the current user is ' . $cookie['uid'];

 ?>
 <html>
  <body>
  <?php if ($cookie) { ?>
  Your user ID is <?= $cookie['uid'] ?>
<?php } else { ?>
  <fb:login-button>Install Example App</fb:login-button>
<?php } ?>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({appId: 'xxxxxx', xfbml: true,cookie:true});
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
    // Reload the application in the logged-in state
    window.top.location = 'http://apps.facebook.com/fbvantivirus';
  });
</script>
<div style="display:none">
  </body>
 </html>
```

I have mention the entire code.please do help me.am struggling from last week..all try in vain.Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome in the Cookie Hell. You need a P3P compact policy.
In the iframe, first line:

```
<?php header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');?>
```